# bootstrap sticky footer but no scroll content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want a sticky bottom footer, which I have, but my content scrolls when it fills the page with content. I want my content to push the footer down instead of scrolling.

How can I achieve this with Bootstrap?

CSS

```
html,
body {
height: 100%;
/* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
 /* Negative indent footer by its height */
 margin: 0 auto -250px;
 /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 250px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
 height: 250px;
}

#footer {
 background-color: #000000;
  border-top:1px solid gray;
 background-image:url('../img/bg1.png');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-position:center bottom; 
}
```

html

```
    <!-- Wrap all page content here -->
<div id="wrap">

  <!-- Begin page content -->
  <div class="container">

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
  </div>
</div>
    <div id="push">
</div>

        <footer id="footer"  class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
                    <div class="container body-content">
            <p style="margin-top:20px;">&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Make-Up Studio Sverige</p>
                        </div>
        </footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to delete the  `class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom"` in the
    `<footer id="footer"  class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">`

The answers i got work in js fiddle as long as you don't put in the bootstrap css.

Answer (score 2):

For example:
HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   Content here
</div>
<div class="footerfix"></div>
<footer>
    <a href="#">Company...</a>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html, body { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
.footerfix{height:4rem;}
footer{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
}
```

Footer has absolute position, to be on the bottom of the page. Footerfix make aditional padding between wrapper and footer. Feel free to add content and you will see that footer is always on the bottom and there is small padding between wrapper and footer.

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HYf7q/5/

Remove dummy text and you can see that footer is on the right place, with or without page content.

**NOTE:**

Body must be relative to the html. In that way, footer is position absolute inside body element. If you remove `position: absolute;` from body, footer will be position absolute to the viewport, and if you have large amount of text on page, it will be on the middle of the page, overlapping text.

Answer (score 1):

try this one..

```
html,body{height:100%;}
#wrap
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -100px; /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
}
#push,#footer{height:100px;}
```

live demo:

with more content: http://jsfiddle.net/HYf7q/2/

with less content: http://jsfiddle.net/SCr7b/3/

thank you...