# Bootstrap footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have read a lot of posts about this but I still didn't find an answer.
**I have a footer that I want to be at the end of the page, not fixed.**
The problem is that the footer is where the content ends. Look at picture.
[image]

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> Mobtech - Privatni korisnici </title>

        <!--Ubaci bootstrap css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="css/basic-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Navigation bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-container">
                        <span class="sr-only"> Pokazi i sakrij navigaciju </span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                         <span> <img src="Slike/logo.png" alt="LogoSlika"/> </span>
                        <font face="Roboto Condensed" size="4" color="green"> Mobtech </font>
                    </a>
                </div> 
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-container">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="index.html"> Početna strana </a> </li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#"> Privatni korisnici </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="poslovni.html"> Poslovni korisnici </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="uredjaji.html"> Uređaji </a> </li>
                        <li><a href="onama.html"> O Nama </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <br />
            <div class="container"> <!--Container -->

                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Kolona na velikom ekranu (lg) prikazuje duzinu jedne kolone, Ekstra small (xs) prikazuje 4 kolone -->
                    <div class="col-lg-12 bg-success"> 
                        <p> Outer div </p>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 bg-primary">
                            <p> Inner div </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer class="mojFooter">
                <font face="Roboto Condensed" size="4"> <center>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 7px;">
                         <p> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &copy; Copyright Ivan Prošić 2016.</p> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom-footer">
                        <div class="col-md-12"> 
                            <ul class="footer-nav">
                                <li> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"> Facebook </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="https://twitter.com/"> Twitter </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href="https://plus.google.com/"> Google+ </a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </font> </center>
            </footer>



            <!-- JavaScript fajl -->
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Kompresovan JavaScript fajl -->
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS, for the footer only:

```
    .mojFooter{
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    color: #00a651;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.bottom-footer{
    border-top: 1px solid #00a651;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    color: #00a651;

}

.footer-nav li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 40px;
}

.footer-nav a{
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: so in other words, you want the footer to be at the end of the page, not fixed, EXCEPT if the content is shorter than the browser window, then you want it to be fixed to the bottom of the page?

Comment: You have my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24916228/1804107

Answer (score 153):

When using **bootstrap 4 or 5**, flexbox could be used to achieve desired effect:

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
    <header>HEADER</header>
    <content>CONTENT</content>
    <footer class="mt-auto"></footer>
</body>
```

Please check the examples: [Bootstrap 4](https://jsfiddle.net/ow5ux9ky/) [Bootstrap 5](https://jsfiddle.net/v2k3d9xL/1/)

In **bootstrap 3** and without use of bootstrap. The simplest and cross browser solution for this problem is to set a minimal height for `body` object. And then set `absolute` position for the footer with `bottom: 0` rule.

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100px; //height of the footer
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Please check this example:
[Bootstrap 3](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lxgnu5b/)

Comment: You can optionally give the body a `padding-bottom` with the height of the footer to prevent the footer from hiding content at the bottom of the body.

Comment: @MrMiketheripper, it works for the original requirement - footer needs to be "at the end of the page, not fixed".

Comment: I have spent the whole day looking for a proper solution and finally found it. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 49):

In my case for Bootstrap4:

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
    <div class="wrapper flex-grow-1"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Upvoting because this uses bootstrap and doesn't require additional CSS

Comment: awesome really worked. But note when using laravel remove the <div id="app"></div>

it also works fine without the  wrapper class.

Comment: My body was acting weird when I uncollapsed my accordion.. The flex-grow class actually helped me out by making it fill all the available space, thanks !

Comment: I have no idea why but I'm using hugo and while this looks like a fairly amazing solution, it won't work for me bootstrap 4.

Comment: I had having problem with `h-100` and `min-vh-100` solve my problem, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can just add:

```
style="min-height:100vh"
```

to your page content container and place the footer in another container

Comment: This is for me the cleanest implementation, but I altered it to `min-height: calc(100vh - [header-height]px - [footer-height]px);` works great.

Answer (score 3):

Use this stylesheet:

```css
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

body > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}

.footer > .container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

code {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you **Robert Beckson** for your answer. I just needed to add mt-auto to the footer and remove a wrapper:

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">        
    <footer class="mt-auto"></footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

© 2021 Company, Inc

```
<a href="/" class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto link-dark text-decoration-none">
  <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"/></svg>
</a>

<ul class="nav col-md-4 justify-content-end">
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Features</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Pricing</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">FAQs</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
    --text: #daf7a6;
    --header: #581845;
    --main: #900c3f;
    --footer: #ff5733;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

header,
main,
footer {
    color: var(--text);
    height: 100px;
    padding: 1rem;
}

header {
    background-color: var(--header);
}

main {
    background-color: var(--main);
}

footer {
    background-color: var(--footer);
    position: sticky;
    top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>content</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```